# SQL Server : merge multiple rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard and have a performance relation to merge multiple rows into one.

Example:

[image]

I can use below query to get data as expected but the performance is not good.
Is there any other query with better performance?

```
WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT 88 ID, 1 AS [OrderFW],'a' AS Code,'n1' as Name UNION
    SELECT 88 ID,2 AS [OrderFW],'a' AS Code,'n2' as Name UNION
    SELECT 88 ID,3 AS [OrderFW],'a' AS Code,'n3' as Name UNION
    SELECT 99 ID,1 AS [OrderFW],'b' AS Code,'n4' as Name UNION
    SELECT 99 ID,2 AS [OrderFW],'b' AS Code,'n5' as Name
)
SELECT 
    d1.Code code1, d1.Name name1, 
    d2.Code code2, d2.Name name2,
    d3.Code code3, d3.Name name3
FROM
    Data d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Data d2 ON d1.ID = d2.ID AND d2.OrderFW = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Data d3 ON d1.ID = d3.ID AND d3.OrderFW = 3
WHERE
    d1.OrderFW = 1
```

Comment: Please be noted that I am using the query in View, so we cannot create temp table. Query only

Comment: @YogeshSharma gives a great solution for this.  In addition to changing the query to the one he suggests, what indexes do you have the that view/the underlying table?  For best performance for the new query, create an index containing columns `Id` and then `OrderFW`.  From your sample data I'd guess this could be a unique column; but you'd have to make that call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with aggregation:

```
select Id, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then code end) as code1,
       max(case when seq = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then code end) as code2,
       max(case when seq = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then code end) as code3,
       max(case when seq = 3 then name end) as name3
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by order) as seq
      from data d
     ) d
group by Id;
```

EDIT : If you have a already `sequence` (i.e. `Order`) then only aggregation is enough :

```
select Id, 
       max(case when [order] = 1 then code end) as code1,
       max(case when [order] = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when [order] = 2 then code end) as code2,
       max(case when [order] = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when [order] = 3 then code end) as code3,
       max(case when [order] = 3 then name end) as name3
from data d
group by Id;
```

**EDIT :** Thanks to [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan) for Demo.

Here is [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8966/2).

Comment: NB: The field `OrderFW` is available for this purpose in the example, so you don't need to generate a new column for this purpose (i.e. you can drop `row_number() over (partition by code order by order) as seq`).

Comment: @JohnLBevan. . . Thanks for fiddle demo.